# Factorising $x^{12} + 1$ into irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{Q} $?

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I calculated that $x^{12} + 1 = (x^4 + 1)(x^8 - x^4 + 1)$

I also know that $x^4 + 1$ is irreducible using Eisenstein's Criterion with $ p=2$ and substituting $x$ with $x + 1$.

My question is, how can I prove that $x^8 - x^4 + 1$ is irreducible?

I tried using Eisenstein's Criterion again but I can't come up with the right substitution and prime.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It may be overkill for this special case, but have you looked into "irreducibility of cyclotomic polynomials"?

Comment: Ah, I see, we have discussed that cyclotomic polynomials are irreducible but weren't given a proper proof of it. So it's basically irreducible as it is the cyclotomic polynomial Φ24(x)

Comment: Just passing by and noticed that we can get the irreducibility of $x^4 + 1$ just from school algebra (i.e. don't have to appeal to Eisenstein's Criterion), at least if we assume uniqueness of factorization. Clearly, there are no linear factors, since there are no real roots. And since $x^4 + 1 = (x^4 + 2x^2 + 1) - 2x^2 = (x^2 + 1)^2 - (\sqrt{2} x)^2 = (x^2 + 1 + \sqrt{2}x)(x^2 + 1 - \sqrt{2}x),$ there are no quadratic factors with rational coefficients.